# Opening .gdb database files

Tags: data-access, interbase, data-extraction

I'm trying to open an old interbase `.gdb` file. This is a new step for me and i don't know where to start any advice would be a great help, I've been searching the internet for the past few days now and i still have to idea how to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting the `.gdb` file to Firebird SQL is a relatively simple path.

[Firebird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_%28database_server%29) is a well known open source database forked from Borland's open source edition of InterBase. It maintains a good degree of compatibility and has many tools / libraries for data access / management.

There are some free migration tools you could use:

- [FBConvert](http://gsbelarus.com/gs/fdbconvert/fdbconvert_eng.html) can convert from Interbase to Firebird format (and doesn't require the presence of a Firebird server on the computer).
- [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/fbexport.php) is a command-line and GUI tool for exporting / importing data from Firebird / InterBase databases. It's based on the IBPP C++ library and runs on both Windows and Linux.
- [Interbase DataPump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp) allows you to pump data and migrate from native Interbase databases into Firebird databases quite easy.

When you have the `.fdb` file, the [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org/) database administration tool allows simple management via GUI.

Take a look at [Drivers Documentation page](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/drivers-documentation/) to access data programmatically.

**PS** if you have a very old Interbase file ([Which version of Interbase or Firebird was a database created under?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9972580/3235496)) then your best bet is to get some old installation of Interbase 5.0, perform a [`gbak`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gbak.html) and restore the database with your Firebird 2.5 installation.

Comment: old interbase file "gdb" can be opened without conversion to firebird even with FlameRobin

Comment: @ValMarinov Yes, thank you for the remark. It's true for not-too-old .gdb files (at least ODS version 10). If so FlameRobin is enough (and the best route). I've listed other tools / options since ODS version is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and advice. it's hard to search the internet for the information you when you have a slow connection. cheers!