# Querying ODS version in use from the Firebird Server

Tags: delphi, firebird

Anybody knows how to query/request programmatically the ODS version from the Firebird server, which will be used for new databases?

Comment: Did you see this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972580/which-version-of-interbase-or-firebird-was-a-database-created-under

Comment: I don't know Delphi, but if you can execute a database information request (`isc_database_info`), then you can query for information items `isc_info_ods_version` and `isc_info_ods_minor_version`.

Comment: I was going to know the ODS version which will be used to create new databases (the ODS version of the server) and not the ODS version of an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

In `MON$DATABASE` you'll find `MON$ODS_MAJOR` and `MON$ODS_MINOR` in an existing database.

Comment: But that assumes that the database is at minimum ODS 11.1, as `MON$DATABASE` was introduced in Firebird 2.1 (ODS 11.1).

Comment: that tells ODS of existing database, but the topicstarter requested one that "will be used for new databases"

Comment: Yes. You have to create dummy database (and then drop it). There's no way to know it upfront. It depends on various options that are known only when actually doing something.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to any database that you can
2. Check the engine version - http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=rdb_get_context

   SELECT RDB$GET_CONTEXT('SYSTEM','ENGINE_VERSION') FROM RDB$DATABASE
3. Map the engine version to native ODS version using Firebird documentation or knowledge base articles like http://www.ibase.ru/prevver/

Comment: That is not going to work, because Firebird 2.5 and earlier will happily use older ODS versions, so engine version is not directly related to the ODS; it just puts a lower and upper limit on it.

Comment: I just realised I misread the question, I thought it was about determining the ODS of an existing database, not for a new one. Unfortunately, the `RDB$GET_CONTEXT` trick will only work for Firebird 2.1 and later, and that you know the ODS mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not found anything useful, I ended up creating a small function, which uses isql to create a bare bone database and extracts the ODS version with direct file access.

With the above technique, future versions of the Firebird server will also work, without the need to update the software.

Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: ....assuming your user would have rights to create the database and the path for temp database would be allowed one. If your program can ensure those requirements, then it can work.